# Get group in between optional groups

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to match the group that contains just "Jack" in the sentences below.
I'd like to make a regex that gets anything after "hello" and either after or before the string "my friend".

```
Greetings, hello my friend Jack
Greetings, hello Jack my friend
Greetings, hello Jack
```

The following doesn't work:

`val test = new Regex("(.*)? (.|,) (hello|hey)? (my friend )?(\\S.*)?(?= my friend))`

Any advice on how to get some group in between optional groups would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` pattern consumes the entire string, so when it tries to match the period-or-comma pattern, there is nothing left to be matched for. This is because the `*` operator is *greedy*: it swallows as much as it can.

There are two simple solutions for this:

1. Use the *lazy* variant `(.*?)?`, which consumes as few character as needed to still match what comes ahead.
2. Instead of using `.` to match everything, use a negated character class to match "everything but what comes ahead". In your example, everything but a comma or a period: `([^.,]*)?`

You can read about this in [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

There are other issues with your regex. For example, the period in the second group will match any character (which makes the `|,` choice redundant).